# Java SQL Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in MySQL called Orders with the details of the order.
I have another table that is called OrderItems.

OrderItems contains the fields: OrderID, ProductID, Qty

Now in java I have a class called Order which has a List.

Lets say I want to get all the Orders from my database including the OrderItems per Order. But I want to do it in the most efficient way possible.

My current solution(which I think might be slow) is:

Loop through a ResultSet of rows and define the OrderDetails, everytime I loop through a row I execute another PreparedStatement and loop through the OrderItems with OrderID of the current Order. I then add the items in the List and go to the next order.

**But I can imagine that this process will be extremely slow and resource intensive. What are the most efficient ways to do this while still being normalized(3NF).**

As per request I have written up an example of my solution

```
public List<Order> getAllOrders() throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>(0);
    ResultSet x = qry("Select * from Orders");
    while(x.next()){
        Order r = new Order();
        //setOrderDetails
        r.setItems(getOrderItems(r));       
    }
    return list;
}
public ArrayList<OrderItem> getOrderItems(Order r) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<OrderItem> list = new ArrayList<OrderItem>(0);
    ResultSet x = qry("Select * from OrderItems where OrderID = "+r.getId()+";");
    while(x.next()){
        OrderItem  newItem = new OrderItem();
        newItem.setOrderId(r.getId());
        newItem.setProduct(null); //Uses some kind of inner join to get the product details
        newItem.setPrice(newItem.getProduct().getPrice());
        newItem.setQuantity(x.getInt(4));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Okay I have followed you guys' suggestions... It still takes on average more than 20 seconds[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxM2J.png)

Log:

```
Time took to connect: 3270ms
Start CustomerService: 38ms
Start ProductService: 1ms
Start OrderService: 2ms
Customer Size: 4
Qry All Customers: 149ms
Products Size: 420
Qry All Products: 391ms
Order already contains: ENALAPRILMALEAAT HCT 20/12,5MG ACTAVIS BV
Add Order(28 items) Took: 2350ms
Qry all orders(27 orders) took: 7929ms
```

This is really hard... it can take up to 20 seconds sometimes.(to qry all orders)

Here is another one still clocking 30 seconds to qry only 28 orders..(all with max 28 items each

```
Time took to connect: 7117ms
Start CustomerService: 35ms
Start ProductService: 1ms
Start OrderService: 1ms
Customer Size: 4
Qry All Customers: 126ms
Products Size: 420
Qry All Products: 700ms
Add Order(6 items) Took: 2117ms
Qry all orders(28 orders) took: 30150ms
```

Comment: It depends, the solution if you only have 5 products and orders, will be different to, if you have 1 billion orders and products.

Comment: IMO getting results using a single join query and then parse resultset to populate order object shall be the right choice.

Comment: Can you post a portion of your code where you are looping?

Comment: I see where you're comming from @Sanjeev.

Comment: @BevynQ lets say that I have about 600 products and I get 4 new Orders weekly.

Comment: @ujulu I have posted a portion of the current solution

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your data (600 products with 4 new order a week) are not so huge that you should need a performance optimization right now. But if you should, you could optimize it if your code looked like the following (I just modified your code a bit):

```
public List<Order> getAllOrders() throws SQLException{
   ArrayList<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>(0);
   PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from OrderItems where OrderID = ?");        // (1)
   ResultSet x = qry("Select * from Orders");
   while(x.next()){
       Order r = new Order();
       //setOrderDetails
       r.setItems(getOrderItems(r, ps));
       list.add(r);    
   }

   return list;
}

public ArrayList<OrderItem> getOrderItems(Order r, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<OrderItem> list = new ArrayList<OrderItem>(0);
    ps.setString(1, r.getId());       // (2)
    ResultSet x = ps.executeQuery();  // (3)
    while(x.next()){
        OrderItem  newItem = new OrderItem();
        newItem.setOrderId(r.getId());
        newItem.setProduct(null); //Uses some kind of inner join to get the product details
        newItem.setPrice(newItem.getProduct().getPrice());
        newItem.setQuantity(x.getInt(4));
    }
    return list;
}
```

What has changed now?

1. The prepared statement is now out of the loop and it will be reused (see change (1)). This should bring a huge performance gain compared to the previous prepared query because the query will be parsed only once.
2. In (2) the param will be set for the current order.
3. In (3) the query will be executed.

Comment: Hey thanks, i did not know about that prepared statement thing.

Comment: But qry(String) creates a new PreparedStatement and executes it already.

Comment: Actually I don't see how you are creating your query. My guess is that this `qry("Select * from OrderItems where OrderID = "+r.getId()+";");` line is creating the query dynamically.(Execuse me if my guess is wrong). The idea is to create the query only once and then just passing the order id every time you query for order items.

Comment: So you're saying executeQuery is not resource intensive but conn.prepareStatement is? EURIKA!

Comment: Compared to parsing a query executing it is not resource intesive, because parsing the query is a lot of work for the database system: syntax checking, validating tables, columns, ...

Comment: But which will take longer?

Comment: I think you can answer the question yourself. Parsing the query takes much longer than executing it.

Comment: Think of it this way: 80% of the work of executing an SQL statement is parsing and optimizing access paths. If the statement doesn't change and the database is mature, then that 80% is repeated on every call and is always returning the same answer. The prepared statement handles that 80% once, and thereafter your application references by a handle, focusing on the 20% of the work that is actually fetching results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, but for those who have slow query times.
Try to set auto commit to false. When you actually create the connection in the code, 
do connection.setAutoCommit(false); and then in the code put connection.commit(); after executing the query. I had the same problem trying to insert 150000 objects, which took about 23 minutes. After setting auto commit to false and then committing, it took me about 27 seconds. I hope it helps.

Here is a code example of the committing:

```
@Override
public void create(Member member) {
    try {
        Connection connection = localConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement sqlInsert = connection.prepareStatement(memberDaoUtil.create());

        sqlInsert.setString(1, member.getMemberId());
        sqlInsert.setString(2, member.getName());
        sqlInsert.setString(3, member.getPersonalNumber());
        sqlInsert.setString(4, member.getUsername());
        sqlInsert.setString(5, member.getPassword());
        sqlInsert.setInt(6, member.getNumOfBoats());
        sqlInsert.setBoolean(7, member.isAdmin());

        sqlInsert.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
        sqlInsert.close();

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then also in the constructor of the connection:

```
private LocalConnection(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which you can see connection.setAutoCommit(false);
You can read in the link below what it does.
[Understand Auto Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/setautocommit-method-sqlserverconnection?view=sql-server-ver15)